# How to remove emacs28 from ubuntu?

Tags: emacs

When I start "emacs" from the terminal Emacs version 28 is opening. I don't know from which package manager, I have installed Emacs.

`which emacs` shows: `/usr/bin/emacs`

I tried removing Emacs with apt-get and snap, but it did not work. How do I remove it?

Comment: If you don't know how you installed it, then it could be tricky to remove it.  Please [edit]  your question and describe what happens when you try to remove it with apt and snap.

Comment: so, i need to remember the package manager i used for each software, right?

Comment: @Melebius, of course not, did you actually read my question?

Comment: You remove software the opposite way of how it was installed. If it's a *snap* you'd expect it to show when you list *snaps* using `snap list`  If it's a *deb* package you installed, you need the package name to remove it, so you could list packages `dpkg -l`  If you have lots of packages you can of course reduce the number shown with `grep` etc ...  These types of commands allow you to find the package/snap/etc name

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by
`sudo apt-get remove emacs-snapshot`.